# Multithreading efficiency and IPC

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, ipc

I have two programs:

1) A python script reading financial data from two brokers. I create two threads for this and leave a while loop in the main section of the code to read instructions from my other program....

2) My other program is a C++ program that creates 1 thread for constantly reading the information from the python script. And a while loop in the main function that is used to place orders.

I am communicating between python and C++ using named pipes.

Everything seems to work. However, there is a HUGE delay between the time the C++ program receives the information and sends it to the python script via the named pipe. On my EC2 server it takes about 100ms to send the information from one place to another. On my i5 computer it takes about 10 ms (it's still a lot, I'd expect microseconds).

What's wrong with my logic? Does multithreading slows down the whole process? Here's some sample code of what I am doing (simplified code):

Python:

```
os.mkfifo("/tmp/botcmd")    # Create pipe
pipecmd = open("/tmp/botcmd", "r")

# This pipe will be used in the threads to send the data to the C++ program
os.mkfifo("/tmp/botdata")    # Create pipe
pipe = open("/tmp/botdata", "r")

# Websocket communication
thread.start_new_thread( start_websocket1,() )
thread.start_new_thread( start_websocket2,() )

while 1:
    try:
        line = pipecmd.readline()
    except:
        print "Could not read cmd pipe"
   print line # It will take at least 10ms to read!!!
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void read_pipe(int arg){

    ifstream pipe("/tmp/botdata"); 
    while(1){
        string line;
        pipe >> line;
        cout << line << endl;
    }

}

void write_pipe(string data){
    ofstream pipe("/tmp/botcmd");  // Open the pipe

    pipe << data << endl;
    pipe.close();
}

int main()
{

    thread t1(read_pipe,0);

    while(1){
        // If I get some x value from python, send this:
        write_pipe("This is where I send the data");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the time since epoch as the timestamp in python to check the delays. i.e when python sends the information at time x, and then c++ reads it, then sends something back, the message will arrive at time x+10ms.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the pipe for each write?  Seems expensive.  I notice your thread functions are called `websocket`, are you using sockets or just pipes?  I ask because TCP_NODELAY socket option can help in these situations (but not with pipes).

Comment: Should I open the pipe just once? I am opening and closing because it's not going to be constantly sending data through the named pipes.Also... I am using websockets to read the data from the broker. I am using named pipes for the IPC between my python script and c++ program.

Comment: By the way, you do know about the GIL I assume?  http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

Comment: No, I did not know about GIL. I am fairly new to multithreading actually. Does that mean that using multiprocesses in a scripting language like python wouldn't make it more efficient?

Comment: The GIL means that a thread blocked on some I/O blocks the entire program. Not very useful, really. Multiprocessing is the better way to go. Also I advise you take a look at zeromq, that's a good wrapper for using pipes and will save you a lot of coding, both in your python and C++

Comment: Don't confuse multithreading with multiprocess, the later is a Python standard library module which uses processes instead of threads.  You can't make generalisations abut the effect of the GIL, that varies depending on the work you are doing.  You mentioned "scripting languages", Ruby has a similar issue, Perl does not - its threads get memory leaks instead :-)  Jython and Iron Python do not have a GIL.